# Can I autonumber a sequence *within* a paragraph?

Tags: microsoft-word, field-codes, numbering

I have a set of several factors I need to repeatedly analyze and discuss -- as applicable -- to different sets of facts.

For instance, if I were declining to admit dogs to my obedience school, I would need to discuss whether they were: (1) the right age; (2) up-to-date on their shots; (3) cute; and (4) actually dogs. So I might send a letter declining to admit two dogs with the following:

> Regrettably, we cannot extend admission offers to Maximus and Socks at this time.
>
> Maximus is ineligible because he is: (1) too old; (2) not up-to-date on his shots; and (3) too adorable.
>
> Socks is ineligible because she is: (1) not up-to-date on her shots; and (2) a cat.

I can get Word to autonumber those items when they're broken out into separate paragraphs, but not when I condense them into a single paragraph, at which point everything in the Maximus paragraph would be numbered (1) and everything in the Socks paragraph would be numbered (2).

Is there a way to keep each of those items numbered in sequence, inside a paragraph?

Bonus points if there's a way to make it automatically reset to 1 with each new paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes, use a SEQuence field.

This was the original numbering system in Word. It is robust and works well.

Here is the [Microsoft Documentation on the field](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/field-codes-seq-sequence-field-062a387b-dfc9-4ef8-8235-29ee113d59be).

Here is [my writing on it](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/numbering.htm#Sequence_Fields).

If you already have a [List Style and MultiLevel List set up](http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html) and want your numbering under that, you can use a [ListNum *field*](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/field-codes-listnum-field-557541b1-abb2-4959-a9f2-401639c8ff82) but you will find this a bit less robust.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome.